# Opening a new tab on button click

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink, navigation

I am wanting to create a link using a button that opens in a new tab.

The code I am using at the moment is currently opening a blank tab, and I'm unsure as to why.

```html
<div class="text text-left">

    <h2>WORK</h2>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pellentesque felis ante, eu convallis sem egestas id.</p>

    <p>Etiam fermentum vestibulum hendrerit. Nam ac felis dolor ultricies varius eget vel arcu.</p>

    <button href="https://www.behance.net" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">View Project</button>

</div>
```

The expected result would be to open a new tab (Behance.com) once the button is clicked - Not a blank tab.

Thanks.

Comment: try to use target="_blank" html attribute
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: use like this: `onclick="(()=>window.open(this.getAttribute('href'),'_blank'))()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute `href` not allowed on element `button` instead of adding `href` just use `data-href` in HTML and in JavaScript just change `this.href` to `this.getAttribute('data-href')` as shown below:

```html
<div class="text text-left">

    <h2>WORK</h2>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pellentesque felis ante, eu convallis sem egestas id.</p>

    <p>Etiam fermentum vestibulum hendrerit. Nam ac felis dolor ultricies varius eget vel arcu.</p>

    <button data-href="https://www.behance.net" onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('data-href')); return false;">View Project</button>

</div>
```

Directly running the code will not work for you due to blocked permission. You may try this in your own project.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I like to do when debugging something like this is `console.log` `this.href`, since you aren't getting what you expect. All signs of problem here point to `this.href`. If you do this you will see that it gives you `undefined`.

What you are looking for is `window.location.href`. Update your onclick to reflect this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score 1):

`this.href` is invalid. Use `this.getAttribute('href')`

<kbd>**[JSFiddle  Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0dh687mc/)**</kbd>

---

However, while this answers your question, this is **not** good practice. 
As [@Sami Ahmed Siddiqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4691401/sami-ahmed-siddiqui) pointed out, `href` is not a valid attribute of the button element. 
Instead you could use a `data-*` attribute such as `data-href`.

Comment: @NathanWilson `href` not allowed on element `button`. Instead you may add `data-href`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<a href="https://www.behance.net" target="_new" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">View Project</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="text text-left">

    <h2>WORK</h2>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pellentesque felis ante, eu convallis sem egestas id.</p>

    <p>Etiam fermentum vestibulum hendrerit. Nam ac felis dolor ultricies varius eget vel arcu.</p>

    <button href="https://www.behance.net" onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('href'),'_blank')" >View Project</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Hard coding the URL is not what the original poster was going for.